# How to access the property of objects obtained after a forEach?

Tags: javascript, loops, object, nested, angular7

I receive from the backend an array of nested objects, I go through them to modify values and filter according to conditions I need for my application

```
      const data = this.market;
      data.forEach(function(item: any, i) {
        if (item.functional_id === 'cool') {
          data.splice(i, 1);
          data.unshift(item);
        }
        if (item.functional_id === 'max') {
          item.name = 'Max min';
        }
        item.products.forEach(function(product) {
          product.items.forEach(function(article) {
            console.log(article);
          });

        });
      });
  }
```

at the console.log point I receive several objects with the structure of the following

```
{
  "name": "Standard",
  "description": "for 50",
  "price": 20,
  "functional_id": "sacs_housse"
}
```

some of the items I get have a price with a decimal point, separated by a dot and I want to check that it has that dot to replace it with a comma.
so I've tried to put a condition on replacing the points. But I don't see a way to access the property since all the type of loop I've tried returns an error.
some of the things I've tried like the following.

```
const data = this.market;
      data.forEach(function(item: any, i) {
        if (item.functional_id === 'cool') {
          data.splice(i, 1);
          data.unshift(item);
        }
        if (item.functional_id === 'furniture') {
          item.name = 'Max min';
        }
        item.products.forEach(function(product) {
          product.items.forEach(function(article) {
            const price = item.price;
            if (price.contains('.')) {
              price.replace(/./g, ',');
            }            
          });

        });
      });
```

someone who sees the mistake I'm making and can help me out.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: `price` is a number. And numbers don't have a `.contains()` nor a `.replace()` method.

Comment: `.replace(/./g, ',')` won't do what you might think it does. Have a look at a regex tutorial and what characters have a special meaning.

Comment: Plus, `const price = item.price;` creates a copy; changing `price` has no effect on `item.price`. Also, you need to use the return value of `.replace()` since it leaves the original string untouched.

Comment: thank U so much! @Andreas I didn't understand why the data couldn't be modified if it was printed by the console.

Comment: Use this to set the output format: https://angular.io/api/common/DecimalPipe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this method in mdn that works perfectly, thanks for everyone's help

```
new Intl.NumberFormat('de-DE').format(item.price);
```

Here's the link to mdn 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat